ethernet recognition issue via usb-hub
When I connect my Ethernet cable via an external USB-hub, it's a rarity, that my laptop's going to recognize the internet connection. Directly connected to my Laptop, it's no problem though (however with a delay of up to 7 seconds).
A few times so far, it happened, that my Laptop was able to establish a connection to the internet via the hub. In those cases, I could also reproduce it when shortly uncoupling the USB-connection cable to the Laptop. It only went away again, when I messed with other connections on the hub (for example added an HDMI cable). However, in the rare case, that the laptop established a connection, it stayed stable while the laptop was turned on.
Important to notice:

There is no driver needed for the hub (specified from seller, see Lemorele-Link below)

I use:

Laptop Dell Latitude 7280
USB-Hub Lemorele TC96 [see here https://us.lemorele.com/products/usb-c-13-in-1-docking-station?_pos=1&_psq=tc96&_ss=e&_v=1.0]
Windows 11

What I've tried:

Network reset in Windows settings ("reset all network adapters to factory settings")
Reinstall Ethernet Connection Driver
untick "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power" in the network driver properties
set the "Locally Administered Address" in Advanced Network Driver Properties to my MAC-Address (without hyphens)
Restarted PC several times
Wiggling on RJ-45-Jack in Hub, which made no difference (so no bad connection)
take off other cables from hub (no positive effect)
connect the power-input from hub (for charging laptop) with energy (I thought it may need power supply...)
tried if it makes any difference, if my laptop currently is charging or not

What I didn't try:

In a post from Kevin Arrows (Link below) concerning a similar kind of problem, he proposed, to change the Network adapters power output. Unfortunately, I wasn't able to find this setting. Maybe it was relocated after an update.

Link to the article from Kevin Arrows: https://appuals.com/ethernet-not-working-when-connected-to-docking-station-dell/

I would try a different USB cable if possible and a definitely a different network cable.

That's a docking station. rather than just a "usb hub". Inspect your system to determine which USB-to Ethernet adapter is built-in to that docking station; check for any updates/newer-version to that adapter's driver

Rather than just the simplistic go/no-go verdict you use (i.e. "recognize the internet connection"), you need to provide a more detailed description of the Ethernet device status and network connection status besides the "internet connection".
